# Создания класса сущности и класса, отвечающего за работу с группой сущностей

Tags: java, наследование

С java на вы, поэтому проблема может оказаться тривиальной. Есть два класса - `Something` и `SomethingGroup`. Вдохновившись тем, что в android-framework `ViewGroup` наследуется от `View` и удобством хранить вперемешку `Something` и `SomethingGroup` в одном списке, `SomethingGroup` прямо унаследовал от `Something`:

```
class Something {
    private String name;
    private int count;

    public Something(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}

class SomethingGroup extends Someting {
    private String name;
    ArrayList<Something> children;

    SomethingGroup(String name, Something ... children) {
        // super(и вот что ему сюда передать?)
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(children));
    }

    public int getCount() {
        int count = 0;
        for(Something s : children) {
            count += s.getCount();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Вся проблема в свойстве `count`. При создании объекта `Something` мы знаем его значение и можем прямо передать его в конструктор, а при создании `SomethingGroup` это значение передается "косвенно" и его надо рассчитать. Как принято поступать в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы используете Java 8, то можно описать Ваше решение более наглядно:

```
    class SomethingGroup extends Something {
        private String name;
        private ArrayList<Something> children;

        SomethingGroup(String name, Something... children) {
            super(name, Stream.of(children).mapToInt(Something::getCount).sum());
            this.children = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(children));
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return this.children.stream().mapToInt(Something::getCount).sum();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
class SomethingGroup extends Something {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Something> children;

    SomethingGroup(String name, Something ... children) {
        super(name, getCountFrom(new ArrayList<Something>(Arrays.asList(children))));
        this.children = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(children));
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return getCountFrom(this.children);
    }

    private static int getCountFrom(ArrayList<Something> children) {
        int count = 0;
        for(Something s : children) {
            count += s.getCount();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Ничего лучше не придумал